# HorizontalPager lost correct fling behaviour after data update

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I tried to update list of data displayed in horizontal pager with tabs. I noticed that after update, horizontal pager fling behaviour going very strange. Sample code is below, bug video [here](https://youtube.com/shorts/bP736vaYIOs?feature=share)

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun Test() {
    Column {
        var pages by remember {
            mutableStateOf(listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))
        }
        val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
        val pagerState = remember(pages) {
            PagerState()
        }
        Row {
            Button(onClick = {
                pages = listOf("1", "2")
            }) {
                Text(text = "2 items")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                pages = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
            }) {
                Text(text = "5 items")
            }
            Button(onClick = {
                pages = listOf("8", "9", "10")
            }) {
                Text(text = "3 items")
            }
        }
        ScrollableTabRow(
            // Our selected tab is our current page
            selectedTabIndex = pagerState.currentPage,
        ) {
            // Add tabs for all of our pages
            pages.forEachIndexed { index, _ ->
                Tab(
                    text = { Text(text = pages[index]) },
                    selected = pagerState.currentPage == index,
                    onClick =
                    {
                        coroutineScope.launch {
                            pagerState.animateScrollToPage(index)
                        }
                    },
                )
            }
        }
        HorizontalPager(
            state = pagerState,
            pageCount = pages.size,
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        ) { page ->
            Box(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxSize()
                    .padding(16.dp)
                    .background(Color.Blue)
            ) {
                Text(text = pages[page])
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any advise.